# Realm list onChanged listener

Tags: realm

I am using realm and Iencountered a problem that is very important to me.

I have a list that using adapter with `RealmResults<TImages>`.

```
myAdapter = new ImagesListAdapter(imagesFromDB);
list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

I added listener for imagesFromDB like this:

```
imagesFromDB.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Object element) {
        //**** Here is the problem ****
    }
}
```

This 'element' is a list of `RealmResults<TImages>`. But it is not good enough because I can only use `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
So it force me to refresh my whole list. Instead I want to use `imagesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(pos)` to refresh only the item in the right pos. But I dont know which `RealmObject` as changed/remove/added.

**How can I know which object from the list as changed?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Realm 3.0 and use the `OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener`: https://realm.io/news/realm-java-3-0-collection-notifications/

Comment: Yes i found that !!

Comment: It is great!! Thanks